# Deserialize JSON to 2 different models

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Does Newtonsoft.JSON library have a simple way I can automatically deserialize JSON into 2 different Models/classes?

For example I get the JSON:

```
[{
  "guardian_id": "1453",
  "guardian_name": "Foo Bar",
  "patient_id": "938",
  "patient_name": "Foo Bar",
}]
```

And I need de-serialize this to the following models:

```
class Guardian {

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "guardian_id")]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "guardian_name")]
  public int Name { get; set; }
}


class Patient {

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "patient_id")]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "patient_name")]
  public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a simple way to deserialize this JSON into 2 Models without having to iterate over the JSON? Maybe JSON property ids will just work?

```
Pair<Guardian, Patient> pair = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
```

Comment: I don't know if you like this, but I used it a lot: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @Thomas Edit | Paste Special

Comment: Is reorganizing the JSON an option?

Answer (score 28):

First off, your models are slightly incorrect. The name properties need to be strings, instead of integers:

```
class Guardian
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "guardian_id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "guardian_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }            // <-- This
}


class Patient
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "patient_id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "patient_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }            // <-- This
}
```

Once you've corrected that, you can deserialize the JSON string into two lists of different types. In your case, `List<Guardian>` and `List<Patient>` respectively:

```
string json = @"[{'guardian_id':'1453','guardian_name':'Foo Bar','patient_id':'938','patient_name':'Foo Bar'}]";
var guardians = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Guardian>>(json);
var patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Patient>>(json);
```

Answer (score 11):

It you want to do it with 1 call, you need to create a class that matches the JSON. That class can then return `Guardian` and `Patient` objects as needed. Also you'll need to use an array or list for the return type because the *source JSON* is an array.

The class to create:

```
public class Pair
{
    public Pair()
    {
        Guardian = new Guardian();
        Patient = new Patient();
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Guardian Guardian { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "guardian_id")]
    public int GuardianID
    {
        get { return Guardian.ID; }
        set { Guardian.ID = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "guardian_name")]
    public string GuardianName
    {
        get { return Guardian.Name; }
        set { Guardian.Name = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "patient_id")]
    public int PatientID
    {
        get { return Patient.ID; }
        set { Patient.ID = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "patient_name")]
    public string PatientName
    {
        get { return Patient.Name; }
        set { Patient.Name = value; }
    }
}
```

And how to use it:

```
var pairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pair[]>(response.Content);

if (pairs.Any())
{
    var pair = pairs[0];
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Guardian.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Patient.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It can't be done with 1 call with the types that you show. You can try using the generic `<T>` approach for each type, also you'll need to use arrays or lists for the return type because the *source JSON* is an array:

```
var guardians = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Guardian[]>(response.Content);
var patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Patient[]>(response.Content);
```

And then combine the two if you need them to be paired. E.g. if you are sure that you always have just one of each:

```
var pair = new Pair(guardians[0], patients[0]);
```

Comment: I added a second answer to show how to do it with 1 Deserialize-call and a class designed to make that possible. See below or above.

Answer (score 9):

Not in one call, and it seems the data is an array, so you need a little more work.

`Zip` is the key method here to join the two separate object lists:

```
Guardian[] guardians = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Guardian[]>(response.Content);
Patient[] patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Patient[]>(response.Content);

var combined = guardians.Zip(patients, (g, p) => Tuple.Create(g, p)).ToList();
```

It would be far more easier to just read the JSON at once, it a single object.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a type to house the two subobjects:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(GuardianPatientConverter))]
class GuardianPatient
{
    public Guardian Guardian { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

And then create a JSON converter to handle the JSON:

```
class GuardianPatientConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(GuardianPatient) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var guardian = new Guardian();
        var patient = new Patient();
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), guardian);
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), patient);
        return new GuardianPatient()
        {
            Guardian = guardian,
            Patient = patient
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
var json = "[{\"guardian_id\":\"1453\",\"guardian_name\":\"Foo Bar\",\"patient_id\":\"938\",\"patient_name\":\"Foo Bar\",}]";
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<GuardianPatient>>(json);
```

and if you want it as an array of pairs:

```
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<GuardianPatient>>(json)
    .Select(o => new Pair(o.Guardian, o.Patient))
    .ToArray();
```

This won't make it any faster, but I suspect you're looking for an easier way to work with the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

One another approach would be creating class that matches JSON format, i.e. class with four properties with corresponding names. Then, deserialize JSON into that class and then use it in your code (set properties of objects with values from JSON, pass deserialized object to constructor of another class).

Answer (score 0):

In your models, The name properties need to be strings, instead of integers. After correcting it.

You can use [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
string json = @"[{'guardian_id':'1453','guardian_name':'Foo Bar','patient_id':'938','patient_name':'Foo Bar'}]";

var combination = new Tuple<List<Guardian>, List<Patient>>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Guardian>>(json), JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Patient>>(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[] 
        {
            new
            {
                guardian_id = "1453",
                guardian_name = "Foo Bar",
                patient_id = "938",
                patient_name = "Bar Foo",
            }
        });

        Guardian[] guardians = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Guardian[]>(json);
        Patient[] patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Patient[]>(json);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since both your objects are the same, wouldn't it make more sense to just have an ID/Name structure of a single base class?  If you need to send all the data at the same time, you can restructure your data and use a data transfer object pattern.  The JSON object would become

```
[{
  "guardian": {
    "id": "1453",
    "name": "Foo Bar"
  },
  "patient": {
    "id" : "938",
    "name": "Foo Bar"
  }
}]
```

And your corresponding data objects would be:

```
public class Record {
  public int id { get; set; } // or string.  I'm not sure which would be more appropriate
  public string name { get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class RecordDto {
  public Record guardian { get; set; }
  public Record patient { get; set; }
}
```

And your API would receive a

```
List<RecordDto>
```

parameter (since you are passing an array of objects).

Comment: Lets assume you cna't just change the JSON model