# .NET Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize from one structure to another?

Tags: json.net

I am in the process of cleaning up a C# object that looks like the following (model reduced for brevity):

```cs
public class Person {
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Address {get;set;}
public string City {get;set;}
}
```

In the code, Person is serialized with JsonConvert to create json:

```json
{"Name":"Test Person","Address":"12345 Main St","City":"Columbus"}
```

I am changing the structure of the class to move the address properties into a separate model.

```cs
public class Person {
public Name {get;set;}
public AddressM {get;set;}
}

public class AddressM {
public string Address {get;set;}
public string City {get;set;}
}
```

Since the database contains json in the original model format, I can't deserialize to Person and retain the address fields.

Is there a way to tell Newtonsoft that the properties have moved?  Or will I need to deserialize into a dynamic object and then manually populate the new model?

Comment: Are you working with a document database?

Comment: MSSQL.  Data is saved to a varchar column.

Comment: I see, and are you dealing with legacy data? or is this a relatively new app?

Comment: legacy data.   There is at least 5 years of data in the current format, spread across 100 databases.  Multi-tenant application using database-per-tenant.

Comment: It's ugly...but you might be forced into using both approaches (if you can't fix the legacy data). You'll need a way of marking the newer data as "v2" or something and then switching your model based on that. Someone might be able to offer a better suggestion, but it's never easy when you need to maintain two separate data models.

Comment: I searched for my question differently and came up with this which might work:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645813/deserialize-json-to-2-different-models.  If I understand this correctly, I should be able to deserialize into Person and then deserialize it again to Person.AddressM.

Comment: But then how do you make sure it works for the legacy data? Would you not need a way to make it switch?

Comment: Adding a version property to the Person class as you had suggested.   The next time the data is saved, if the version property is not set, it will save using the new model.  On reading, it would check for the version and use the appropriate deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

as i see you need a custom converter. i made example for you. normally you need to check if object exists...etc..

```cs
void Main()
{
    string j = "{\"Name\":\"Test Person\",\"Address\":\"12345 Main St\",\"City\":\"Columbus\"}";
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(j).Dump();
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public AddressM Address { get; set; }
    public Person() {Address = new AddressM();}
}

public class AddressM
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}


class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Person);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        string name = (string)obj.SelectToken("Name");
        string addressLine1 = (string)obj.SelectToken("Address");
        string city = (string)obj.SelectToken("City");
        return new Person() {Name = name, Address = new AddressM(){Address = addressLine1, City = city}};
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image]